# Flutter: How to add entry to map if it not contains key from other map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two maps `answers` and `photos`. In my function I have third map witch I filled with `photos` maps data. And now I want to add answers data to this map as well. Thing is both answers and photos have same keys, but different data. So I need to add only entries with different key. Here is simplified example:

```
void testFunction() {
  Map<String, String> answers = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3',
    'key4': 'value4',
    'key5': 'value5',
  };
  Map<String, String> photos = {
    'key3': 'svalue3',
    'key4': 'svalue4',
  };

  Map<String, String> result = {};

  for (final entry in photos.entries) {
    result.putIfAbsent(entry.key, () => entry.value);
  }

  //Here I need to add answers entries to result map if result does not contain same key

  print('Results map data = ${result}');
}
```

What I want to output is `Results map data = {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: svalue3, key4: svalue4, key5: value5}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do exactly the same for answers after it

```
for (final entry in answers.entries) {
  result.putIfAbsent(entry.key, () => entry.value);
}
```

That is what `putIfAbsent` does, it only puts it if absent, as the name implies

Answer (score 4):

Another way to look at it, that seems simpler in my opinion, is that you want to merge the two maps, `photos` and `answers` with entries in `photos` overwriting any entry in `answers` that have the same key.

In that case you can just do a simple map merge:

```dart
Map<String, String> result = {...answers, ...photos};
```

Your function would look like this.

```dart
void testFunction() {
  Map<String, String> answers = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3',
    'key4': 'value4',
    'key5': 'value5',
  };
  Map<String, String> photos = {
    'key3': 'svalue3',
    'key4': 'svalue4',
  };
 Map<String, String> result = {...answers, ...photos};
  print('Results map data = ${result}');
}
```

Console output:

```
Results map data = {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: svalue3, key4: svalue4, key5: value5}
```

Comment: that's a very clever way to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
void testFunction() {
  Map<String, String> answers = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3',
    'key4': 'value4',
    'key5': 'value5',
  };
  Map<String, String> photos = {
    'key3': 'svalue3',
    'key4': 'svalue4',
  };

  Map<String, String> result = {};
  result.addAll(photos);
  for (final entry in answers.entries) {
    result.putIfAbsent(entry.key, () => entry.value);
  }


  print('Results map data = ${result}');
}
```

UPD: or you can even skip this check `if(!photos.containsKey(entry.key))`

Comment: (You left in a comment that doesn't apply.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, String> result = Map.from(photos);

for (final entry in answers.entries) {
  result.putIfAbsent(entry.key, () => entry.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in your case you want to add the second the second map to the first one and override the entries.

```
 result.addAll(answers);

 photos.forEach((key,value){
    answers[key] = value;
  });
```

result = {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: svalue3, key4: svalue4, key5: value5}

[image]

Comment: I just added a picture

Comment: indeed answers map is being replaced with results map. It just needs .addAll let me fix my code :P